# How to fetch hierachical spatial structure and contained products from an IFC model?

Tags: ifc, bim

I am currently working on a project to fetch all the details like IfcBuilding, IfcDistributionControlElement etc. from an IFC file stored in Opensource BIMserver. Using the Java client library, I managed to get a list of storeys and print their names.

```java
List<IfcBuildingStorey> storeys = model.getAllWithSubTypes(IfcBuildingStorey.class));
for (IfcBuildingStorey storey : storeys) {
    System.out.println(storey.getName());
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
Level 4
```

What i want is for each **storey**, e.g. Level 2, to get all the **rooms** located in that storey, and then all **entities** of type IfcProduct, e.g. fire detectors, inside those rooms in a hierarchical way.

**Expected Output:**

```
Level 2
  Room 1: entity 1, entity 2, entity 3, entity 4
  Room 2: entity 1, entity 2, entity 3, entity 4
  Room 3: entity 1, entity 2, entity 3, entity 4
```

Comment: Most walls are not inside rooms, but between at least 2 different rooms. After all that is their purpose, to separate one part of space from another part of space. How does that fit into a hierarchical structure?

Comment: I guess i misguided somehow, what i want to achieve is i need a fire detector from Room 1 and if i give some condition on the fire detector i must be able to highlight the Room 1 in the UI, but to achieve that i need to segregate the data , that is Detector A room one is active ,did you get my point?

Comment: Given a set of IfcBuildingStorey entities (e.g. Level 1-4), you want for each storey the rooms (e.g. Room 1-3) in that storey and for each room, all contained entities of type IfcProduct (e.g. fire detector). - Is that your question? The Java code seems irrelevant for that. It is more a question of how things are modelled in the IFC

Comment: you understood the question correct. Yes this code is how i tried and i know that it is not the right way, can you provide some help? i googled a lot but didn't get any help.

Comment: well ! i am able to achieve what i wanted but had to use multiple loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the list of `IfcBuildingStorey` entities you would have to work your way through the spatial hierarchy as described in the [IFC Documentation](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC4/Add2TC1/html/link/ifcbuildingstorey.htm). Be aware that you do not necessarily have a simple two-level structure of `IfcBuildingStorey` and `IfcSpace`, but the aggregation tree may contain up to three hierarchy levels of storeys as well as of spaces:

1. groups of storey/space (compositiontype COMPLEX) composed of
2. storey/space elements (compositionType ELEMENT) composed of
3. storey/space parts (compositionType PARTIAL).

You reach the respective next lower level via the objectified aggregation relationship:

- `IfcSpatialStrutureElement.IsDecomposedBy`
- `IfcRelAggregates.RelatedObjects`
- `IfcObjectDefinition`

Then hope that the `IfcObjectDefinition` instance is a spatial structure (it should be, but you never know).

In Java this could look like this:

```java
void traverseSpatialStructure(IfcSpatialStructureElement parent){
  for (IfcRelAggregates aggregation: parent.getIsDecomposedBy()){
    for (IfcObjectDefinition child: aggregation.getRelatedObjects()){
      doSomeThingWith(child); // e.g. print name
      assert child instanceof IfcSpatialStructureElement;
      traverseSpatialStructure((IfcSpatialStructureElement) child);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, once you reached the `IfcSpace` level, use the spatial containment relation to get hold of every product contained in the space:

- `IfcSpatialStructureElement.ContainsElements`
- `IfcRelContainedInSpatialStructure.RelatedElements`
- `IfcProduct`

In Java again:

```java
void doSomethingWith(IfcSpace spatialStructure){
  for(IfcRelContainedInSpatialStructure containment: spatialstructure.getContainsElements()){
    for(IfcProduct product : containment.getRelatedElements()){
      // do something with your product, e.g. fire detector
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes this is how did it, for reference i used the bimviews plugin to identify the relations, but your explanation was very much needed also the documentation, thanks for the input.

Comment: I would always suggest to consult the schema. Figuring something out based on a specific model instance may be a good starting point, but if you stop there, your solution will be limited to input similar to that particular case.

Comment: Hi @hlg i have a question as i am confused , i have to use the 3D view of BimViews in a Spring-boot application. Should i create a new plugin or can i use the existing plugin(which is in java script) and try to integrate it to the current spring-boot application, or can i achieve the same(3D) using Java? i am confused. As i will have to start JavaScript from the scratch